# Phenotype case/control study

Tags: file, statistics, syntax-error, controls, case

Can you help me. I wanted to do a case/control study, but I can't separate the groups.

I am correcting the phenotype in the ped file, but plink is gives an error. Line 1 of .ped file has fewer tokens than expected.

I will be glad for any help.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.